# Python - Differences between numpy asarray assignment

Tags: python, numpy

What is the difference between

```
train_x = np.asarray([[0.0], [1.0], [2.0], [3.0], [4.0]])
train_y = np.asarray([1.0, 1.1, 3.0, 2.0, 5.0])
```

in Python numpy.asarray assignment?
What is the meaning of [] brakets in the first line?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is creating a numpy array from a list of floats (1D) vs creating an array from a list of list of floats (2D)